# Variables in javax.el API

Tags: java, el

I don't really understand how variables work in javax.el:

```
// Implemented by the EL implementation:
ExpressionFactory factory = ExpressionFactory.newInstance();

// Implemented by the user:
ELContext context = ...;

Object result = factory.createValueExpression(context1, "${foo.bar}", Object.class).getValue1(context);
```

Why is it needed to pass the context twice. Is it possible to pass two different contexts? Which is used for what purpose? What is the expected result of:

```
ValueExpression expr = factory.createValueExpression(context1, "${foo.bar}", Object.class).getValue(context2);
```

The javadoc of ExpressionFactory#createValueExpression /JSR-245 explains that:

```
The FunctionMapper and VariableMapper stored in the ELContext are used to resolve
functions and variables found in the expression. They can be null, in which case
functions or variables are not supported for this expression. The object returned
must invoke the same functions and access the same variable mappings regardless
of whether the mappings in the provided FunctionMapper and VariableMapper
instances change between calling ExpressionFactory.createValueExpression()
and any method on ValueExpression.
```

Furthermore "JSR-245 2.0.7 EL Variables" explains:

```
An EL variable does not directly refer to a model object that can then be resolved
by an ELResolver. Instead, it refers to an EL expression. The evaluation of that
EL expression gives the EL variable its value.

[...]

[...] in this [...] example:
<c:forEach var=“item” items=“#{model.list}”>
    <h:inputText value=“#{item.name}”/>
 </c:forEach>
```

While creating the “#{item.name}” expression, the "item" variable is mapped (in the VariableMapper) to some ValueExpression instance and the expression is bound to this ValueExpression instance. How is this ValueExpression created and how is it bound to different elements of "model.list"? How should this be implemented? It is possible to
create the ValueExpression once and reuse it for each iteration:

```
 <!-- Same as above but using immediate evaluation -->
 <c:forEach var=“item” items=“${model.list}”>
    <h:inputText value=“${item.name}”/>
 </c:forEach>

ValueExpression e1 = factory.createExpression(context,"#{model.list}");
variableMapper.setVariable("item", ??);
ValueExpression e2 = factory.createExpression(context,"#{item.name}");
for(Object item : (Collection<?>) e1.getValue(context)) {
   ??
}
```

Or is it necessary to create a new ValueExpression for iteration:

```
ValueExpression e1 = factory.createExpression(context,"#{model.list}");        
for(Object item : (Collection<?>) e1.getValue(context)) {
   variableMapper.setVariable("item", factory.createValueExpression(item,Object.class));
   ValueExpression e2 = factory.createExpression(context,"#{item.name}");
   Object name = e2.getValue(context);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Q: Are you doing this for some web application (e.g. inside of Tomcat)?  Q: have you seen the "Unified Expression Language" documentation: http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/reference/techart/unifiedEL.html

Comment: Some interesting things on this page. However is focuses on the using EL in some existing EL-enables framework and on extending existing EL frameworks with EL features (custom resolver, tags ...). It doesn't explain anything about how integrating EL into your framework (using ExpressionFactory, VariableMapper, FunctionMapper ...).

Comment: I'm trying to resolve EL expressions out of JSP, JSF. Things like (simplified) : Collection<Date> dates = helper.map(events, "${this.date}"). Might be simpler to use another EL (SpEL ...) though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it needed to pass the context twice. Is it possible to pass two
>   different contexts? Which is used for what purpose?

The `variableMapper` and `functionMapper` are only used at parse time (factory.createMethod(...)) while the `elResolver` is used during evaluation (expr.getValue(...)). Using different contexts to parse and evaluate an expression is fine.

> While creating the “#{item.name}” expression, the "item" variable is
>   mapped (in the VariableMapper) to some ValueExpression instance and
>   the expression is bound to this ValueExpression instance. How is this
>   ValueExpression created and how is it bound to different elements of
>   "model.list"? How should this be implemented?

First of all: forget about "variables". As explained in the Javadoc, their values are expressions, provided at parse time. Think of EL variables as constants or macros. You cannot redefine them, they are "burned" into the expression.

What you need is EL's mechanism to resolve *properties*. In the following working example, I'm using an `ELContext` implementation from [JUEL](http://juel.sf.net), just to keep things simple and focus on the relevan EL usage:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import javax.el.ELContext;
import javax.el.ExpressionFactory;
import javax.el.ValueExpression;

import de.odysseus.el.util.SimpleContext;

public class Sof9404739 {
  /**
   * Sample item
   */
  public static class MyItem {
    String name;
    public MyItem(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Sample model
   */
  public static class MyModel {
    List<MyModel> list;
    public List<?> getList() {
      return list;
    }
    public void setList(List<MyModel> list) {
      this.list = list;
    }
  }

  /**
   * EL expression factory
   */
  static ExpressionFactory factory = ExpressionFactory.newInstance();

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    /**
     * Simple EL context implementation from JUEL
     */
    ELContext context = new SimpleContext();

    /**
     * Define the two expressions
     */
    ValueExpression listExpr =
      factory.createValueExpression(context, "#{model.list}", List.class);
    ValueExpression nameExpr =
      factory.createValueExpression(context, "#{item.name}", String.class);

    /**
     * This looks like a variable, but it isn't - it's a "root property"
     */
    context.getELResolver().setValue(context, null, "model", new MyModel());

    /**
     * Just for fun, initialize model's list property via EL, too
     */
    context.getELResolver().setValue(context, "model", "list",
        Arrays.asList(new MyItem("alice"), new MyItem("bob")));

    /**
     * Evaluate expressions like c:forEach
     */
    for (Object item : (List<?>) listExpr.getValue(context)) {
      /**
       * For each item, define the "item" (root) property
       */
      context.getELResolver().setValue(context, null, "item", item);
      System.out.println(nameExpr.getValue(context)); // "alice", "bob"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something similar.